# How do I remove everything in between a set of parentheses in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a panda Dataframe called 'Energy' with a column named 'Country'. In 'Country' are entries that include information enclosed by a set of parentheses.  A second issue is the removal of numbers from similar strings. The potential solutions I have come up with after reading in stackoverflow - seem not to work.  I have ensured that the Dtype for the 'Country' column is 'string'.

I located a similar example in stackoverflow and tried all those combinations.  After I tried each in turn I would run the statement 'print(Energy.Country[98])' which was a test to see if the example worked to remove the parentheses.

Example1: Iran (Islamic Republic of)
Desired result1 : Iran

Example 2: Netherlands12
Desired result 2 : Netherlands

The actual code was:

```
Energy['Country'] = Energy['Country'].str.replace(r" \(.*\)","")
```

When I tested the output for the Iran example it had remained unaffected. Similarly for the code to remove numbers:

```
Energy['Country'] = Energy['Country'].str.replace(r"([0-9]+)$","")
```

I have also tested a wide variety of re.compile combinations

`rem = re.compile('\(.*\)')`

`Energy.Country.str.replace(rem,'',regex=True)`

I have come to the conclusion that I must be missing something from my spyder environment! I did import pandas, numpy and re to be sure but still cannot find my error.

I also tried contains and even extractall!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to learn more about [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Please find below a potential solution of your problem:

```
Energy['Country'] = Energy['Country'].str.replace(r'\s+\([^()]*\)$', '', regex=True)
```

Where

- `r'\d+'` is a regex pattern that matches one or more digits
- `r'\s+\(.*\)'` is a regex pattern where `\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters, `\(` matches the opening parenthesis, `.*` matches any characters (except newline), and `\)` matches the closing parenthesis. This finds and removes the entire content within the parentheses, including the parentheses themselves and any preceding whitespace.

Comment: This solution works quite elegantly.  Thanks!  I did get another method that does not involve the 'str' argument! 
Energy.Country.replace(' \(.*','',regex=True, inplace=True)....I will have to decipher the replace string definition....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of remove what you don't want, maybe you should keep what you want:

```
# Output
>>> Energy['Country'].str.extract('^([^\d\(]+)', expand=False).str.strip()
0           Iran
1    Netherlands
Name: Country, dtype: object

# Alternative
>>> Energy['Country'].str.split(r'(\d|\s*\()').str[0]
0           Iran
1    Netherlands
Name: Country, dtype: object

# Input
>>> Energy['Country']
0    Iran (Islamic Republic of)
1                 Netherlands12
Name: Country, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  Right after submitting the question I discovered a different way....

Energy.Country.replace(' \(.*','',regex=True, inplace=True)

Comment: I immediately tried the possibilities you provided.  It seems, on my machine and install of spyder, that the str.extract as well as the alternative does not get the anticipated result.  I did import pandas, numpy and re at the top of the code.  But after using both, neither test for removal of the info worked to produce the desired result....any thoughts on why ...did I not install something..??

Comment: What is your version of `Pandas`? Try: `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: My version of Pandas is 2.1.1....in Spyder 5.4.3